# How to convert a video with openCV without increasing to filesize?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I am using the following code to blur a selection of frames of a video. I noticed that after this, the new video is double the size of the old video. How can I make sure that the file size doesn't change?

I did make sure that the width, height, and framerate is the same in the old and the new video.

My original video is about 2h long and 2.5GB. The partly blurred video is 5GB.

This is my code:

```
WIDTH = 960 # pixels
HEIGHT = 540 # pixels

# input video
video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

# output video
video_FourCC = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
video_out = cv2.VideoWriter("video_blurred.mp4",
                            video_FourCC, 
                            FPS,                     # FPS
                            (WIDTH, HEIGHT))        # video size

def blur_video():
    frame_nb = 0
    while(video.isOpened()):
        
        ret, frame = video.read()
        
        if ret == True: 
            if (frame_nb > 10000) & (frame_nb < 20000]):
        
                # blur frame
                frame = cv2.blur(frame, (200,200))
                
            video_out.write(frame)
    
            frame_nb += 1
            print(frame_nb)
        else:
            break   
        
blur_video()


video.release()
video_out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The video size might be increasing since blurred frames have less in common with each other. Video files are smaller than the sum of their images because they can chart just the differences between each frame and compress on that. Blurred frames probably look very different from one to the next and could be messing with the compression scheme.

Comment: The VideoIO part of OpenCV is more of a convenience thing, there are very few [things you can adjust](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga41c5cfa7859ae542b71b1d33bbd4d2b4) and you're using the defaults... so the outcome is not really surprising. I'd look for a tool that's focused on video editing and encoding, or at least a library that directly wraps a codec and gives you full control over all its parameters.